# How can I override strings?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to change a label of Drupal 8's contact form ('Your email address'). The label is defined /core/modules/contact/src/MessageForm.php, but obviously I don't want to change this in core.

```
$form['mail'] = array(
'#type' => 'email',
'#title' => $this->t('Your email address'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
```

In Drupal 7 I always used [string overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) but the module isn't available for Drupal 8 yet. How can string be overridden in Drupal 8?

Comment: It looks like there _is_ a usable version of this module for Drupal 8, according to this post from a year ago: https://www.drupal.org/node/2236791

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. Looks like it isn't even alpha though - will try the custom method first.

Comment: This is an example of a question where we may have a duplicate already for how to override a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest method would be to implement a hook_form_alter inside a custom module that overrides the title

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x

Some information how to create custom module.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules

Comment: This hook can also be used from the theme layer, too.

Comment: Thanks... and ouch, that's complicated. Lots of reading on creating custom modules to do...

Comment: @Kevin, correct :) I always forget to mention that

Answer (score 6):

You can always override strings in `settings.php` like this:

```
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Related entities for @group' => 'Add Content to group @group',
);
```

You can change `en` to `de` or whatever two letter language code you like.

Please note: the entire string must exist by itself. For example, the above string override existed in the group module controller like this:

```
return $this->t('Related entities for @group', ['@group' => $group->label()]);
```

This will NOT work:

```
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Related entities for ' => 'Add Content to ',
);
```

So for the example listed in the question, you could use:

```
$settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Your email address' => 'Your email ID',
);
```

Comment: Yep, sometimes it is much easy just to add override for core string or config