# How to change the default search button value in awesome zymphonies free theme?

Tags: search

please have a look at the site, http://35.187.238.51/jrdtml/. This is a prototype site of the library I'm working for. I'm using Drupal 8.4 with Awesome Zymphonies free theme. I would want to change the text in the default Search box from 'Search' to 'Site Search'. Also I would like the Search box to appear in different pages other than just the Home page.

Thanks for your attention.

Best, Francis

Answer (score 0):

**How to override the search text string**

For how to change the text of the search box, you'll need to do a string override.  [See the answer to this question on how to write your own custom module to do this.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233142/how-can-i-override-strings)

Drupal also has a String Overrides module so that you don't have to write your own code, but it's not ready for Drupal 8 yet.  [There is a test version here but it's not safe for production sites.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2236791)

A third way to do this-- and perhaps the easiest approach if you will be changing lots of Drupal interface text-- is to add "English" as a translatable language on the language settings page (`admin/config/regional/language`) and then disable the original "English."  What this allows you to do is "translate" any text that appears in the Drupal UI.

**How to show the search box on other pages**

The search box is (most likely) a block that can be controlled on the block administration page: `/admin/structure/block`.

You can edit the block settings to choose which pages it appears on.  You can also place additional search blocks and then edit the settings to show them in different places on different pages.